# trigger to update a custom field in account when related opportunity is created with same value as in custom field of Opportunity

Tags: triggers, salesforce

Can someone please elaborate what is mapAccounts.get(opp.AccountId) is getting here `MapAccount acc = mapAccounts.get(opp.AccountId);`

```
trigger OppTrigger on Opportunity (after insert) {   
    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isAfter)
    {
        Set<Id> acctSet = new Set<Id>();
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
        {
            acctSet.add(opp.AccountId);
        }

        Map<Id, Account> mapAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT Id, accField__c FROM Account where Id IN :acctSet]);
        for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new)
        {
            Account acc = mapAccounts.get(opp.AccountId);
            acc.accField__c = opp.oppField__c;
            accList.add(acc);
        }
        Update accList;
    }

}
```

there is no error in this trigger but i need to understand in detail, what `mapAccounts.get(opp.AccountId);` is getting here

Answer (score 1):

It's getting the sObject instance from `mapAccounts` corresponding to the Account assigned to the Opportunity `opp`.

This is a common bulkification pattern to allow two sObjects to be queried and related to one another in Apex without running SOQL in a loop, which consumes an unacceptable amount of governor limits.